# Android R.Java not Generating even when new project is created

Tags: android, r.java-file

I know This Question has been asked multiple time here, i already have been through many of them.
I tired every solutions which were provided by the experts.
my problem still persist.

I my case R.java file is not generated even when a new project is created.
even after cleaning and rebuilding also.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Did u check if there is any error in your xml files?

Comment: I have already tried these approaches....

Comment: then may be re installing eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there are no error in your .xml files where they refer to another which is non-existent
2. Make sure you don't have any upper case letters in your file names.

Comment: i Checked all of my XML files the only have warnings 
No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document

No Errors...

Even Every new project is created without R.java file

Comment: Make sure they're not refering to another file you have deleted. I'm not sure if Eclipse or other IDEs throw an error for that. And doubly check that there are no upper case letters in ANY file names you've made as android is very picky. Once you've done that open the manifest, add a space and then save it. that normally forces the R.java to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same kinds of problems but after so much of searching i have found that when cleaning the project in the cleaning window select the option "Build Only Selected Project" At the bottom of the Clean window.

[image: See At the bottom for option that i have selected to recover R.java file]

Answer (score 0):

The Same problem happened to me also,May be you updated the eclipse.

1.Check that Android SDK Build-tools is installed. Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools
2.Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ASK Build-tools. Build fails silently if they don't match.

Solution

1.Update Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools from Android SDK Manager (**Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools**).Then restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following steps::

1. connect internet to your system(3G internet connection will be preffered)
2. start eclipse.
3. Open SDK Manager
4. see at top of sdk manager window
5. Check Android Sdk Build tools
6. click on a button a right bottom corner "install 1 package".
7. wait untill package installs
8. after installing ,restart eclipse

Now your issue will resolve certainly